# CouchDB taking lot of space due to revisions

Tags: couchdb

We have a project that involved with a database sync with pouchdb in mobile devices. We have faced issue when updating multiple documents (8400 docs per minute), internal storage increasing (around 20MB per minute) frequency.
We figured one main reason for that couchdb revisions. So we decided to decrease database rev_limit to around 5. But we heard it may impact replication process between couchdb and pouchdb. My first question is
how this decrease of revision limit impact to the replication process?.

And we figured out views taking more space than normal document storage. My second question, is there any way to reduce couchdb view size?

Comment: Have you tried running [compaction](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/maintenance/compaction.html) yet? That's intended to remove the extra disk space being used up by old revisions.

Comment: Yep. It reduce space around a half. But still it it's significant amount of space compared to traditional dbs like MySQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your data model (fast updates) doesn't play to CouchDB's strengths. Even after compaction, old revisions (including tombstones) take up space. CouchDB is happiest when using small, immutable documents. Such a model is also less likely to suffer from update conflicts.

Look to your documents - can they be broken apart such that updates can be changed to new document writes? Typical indicators are nested objects or arrays that grow in documents over time.

Comment: If _revs_limit is set for a database, then  on compaction the limit is applied for tombstones too (according documentation)